# CallNamedPipe and TransactNamedPipe don't work

Tags: c, winapi, ipc, named-pipes

I want to send message to server and read it using named pipes. When I use WriteFile function, the message gets to the server, but TransactNamedPipe fails with error 230 (ERROR_BAD_PIPE) and CallNamedPipe fails with error 87 (INVALID_PARAMETER) or 231 (PIPE_BUSY). I've tried MSDN examples, a lot of other stuff, but still no results. Please help.

Client:

```
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <string>

#define BUFSIZE 512

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR *argv[])
{
    OVERLAPPED ov;
    ZeroMemory(&ov, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

    HANDLE hPipe;
    // Try to open a named pipe; wait for it, if necessary. 
    while (1)
    {
        hPipe = CreateFile(
            L"\\\\.\\pipe\\PipeTest",   // pipe name 
            GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
            GENERIC_WRITE,
            0,              // no sharing 
            NULL,           // default security attributes
            OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
            FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,             
            NULL);          // no template file 

                            // Break if the pipe handle is valid. 
        if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            break;

        DWORD lastErr = GetLastError();

        // Exit if an error other than ERROR_PIPE_BUSY occurs. 
        if (GetLastError() != ERROR_PIPE_BUSY)
        {
            printf("Could not open pipe\n");
            return 0;
        }

        // All pipe instances are busy, so wait for 2 seconds. 
        if (!WaitNamedPipe(L"\\\\.\\pipe\\PipeTest", 2000))
        {
            printf("Could not open pipe\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    std::wstring s;
    s.resize(1024);
    DWORD cbRead;

    BOOL fSuccess = TransactNamedPipe(
        hPipe,                  // pipe handle 
        L"Hello",              // message to server
        sizeof(wchar_t) * 5, // message length
        &s[0],
        s.size() * sizeof(wchar_t),
        &cbRead,                // bytes read
        &ov);                  // not overlapped 

    DWORD lastErr = GetLastError();
    GetOverlappedResult(hPipe, &ov, &cbRead, TRUE);
    DWORD lastErr2 = GetLastError();

    CloseHandle(hPipe);

    return 0;
}
```

Server:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

const std::wstring pipeName = L"\\\\.\\pipe\\PipeTest";

int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hPipe;
    wchar_t buffer[256];
    DWORD dwRead;

    OVERLAPPED ov;
    ZeroMemory(&ov, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

    hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(pipeName.c_str(),
        PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX | PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE,   // FILE_FLAG_FIRST_PIPE_INSTANCE is not needed but forces CreateNamedPipe(..) to fail if the pipe already exists...
        PIPE_WAIT,
        1,
        1024 * 16,
        1024 * 16,
        NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,
        NULL);

    if (hPipe != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        if (ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, &ov) != FALSE)   // wait for someone to connect to the pipe
        {
            while (ReadFile(hPipe, buffer, 255, &dwRead, &ov) != FALSE)
            {
                WriteFile(hPipe, L"lalala", 6 * sizeof(wchar_t), &dwRead, &ov);

                DWORD lastErr1 = GetLastError();
                GetOverlappedResult(hPipe, &ov, &dwRead, TRUE);
                DWORD lastrr2 = GetLastError();

                printf("%s", buffer);
            }
        }

        DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the functions work correctly. Your program however, is defective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you read about [TransactNamedPipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365790(v=vs.85).aspx)

> TransactNamedPipe fails if the server did not create the pipe as a
>   **message-type** pipe or if the pipe handle is not in message-read mode.

and [CallNamedPipe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365144(v=vs.85).aspx)

> Calling CallNamedPipe is equivalent to calling the CreateFile (or
>   WaitNamedPipe, if CreateFile cannot open the pipe immediately),
>   **TransactNamedPipe**, and CloseHandle functions

so this functions work only message-type pipe

but when you create server pipe you use `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE | PIPE_READMODE_BYTE`
so CallNamedPipe and/or TransactNamedPipe and must fail.

you need use ReadFile/WriteFile instead. or create server with flags `PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE|PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE` and call [SetNamedPipeHandleState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365787(v=vs.85).aspx) for client handle for set it message-read mode (use `PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE`)

Comment: When I put PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE|PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE in CreateNamedPipe I get error 87 immediately - invalid_parameter.

Comment: Your posted code passes the pipe type and mode in the second argument, they must be passed in the third argument.  It only seemed to work before because `PIPE_TYPE_BYTE` and `PIPE_READMODE_BYTE` happen to be equal to 0.